# Douady spaces of deformation equivalent surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be deformation equivalent complex surfaces. Is it true that the $n$-th Douady spaces $X^{[n]}$ and $Y^{[n]}$ are deformation equivalent?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  Yes that is true.  If you have a proper, submersive, holomorphic map of complex manifolds, $f:\mathcal{X}\to S$, then there is a relative Douady space of the morphism that is a complex analytic space with a morphism to $S$ whose fibers are the Douady spaces of the fibers of $f$.  The usual infinitesimal deformation theory proof of smoothness of $X^{[n]}$ (which goes back to Fogarty) also implies that the relative Douady space is submersive over $S$.